# Oracle Linux 6.8 to 7.x upgrade

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

I'm trying to upgrade my Oracle Linux OS from 6.8 t0 7.x version by following the steps provided here https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/7/relnotes7.5/ol7-upgrade-ol6.html

However, I'm getting stuck with the below step where I get the **treeinfo** not found error.

```
redhat-upgrade-tool-cli --network=7.5 --instrepo=http://yum.oracle.com/​repo/​OracleLinux/​OL7/​UEKR5/​RDMA/​x86_64 --debuglog=/tmp/upgrade.log --cleanup-post
```

**ERROR**

```
redhat_upgrade_tool.yum ERROR: Error downloading .treeinfo or treeinfo from repo http://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR5/RDMA/x86_64/: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

I'm not sure whether it's possible to do an in-place upgrade for OLS or not, any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Download iso from yum repository
http://yum.oracle.com/ISOS/OracleLinux/OL7/u8/x86_64/OracleLinux-R7-U8-Server-x86_64-dvd.iso

Mount it externally (or internally) and run upgrade

```
redhat-upgrade-tool-cli --force --device=/media/cdrom --debuglog=/tmp/upgrade.log
```